# ASP Validation Error

Tags: asp.net, validation

I am trying to use validators to make sure that a user supplies a name and a number between 1 and 99. Here is the code:

```
<p>
            <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="jerseyBox" ErrorMessage="Jersey number must be between 1 and 99" MaximumValue="99" MinimumValue="0"></asp:RangeValidator>
        </p>
        <p>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="jerseyBox" ErrorMessage="Must supply a jersey number"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </p>

        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="nameBox" ErrorMessage="Must Supply A Name"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
[InvalidOperationException: WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive).]
   System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.EnsureJqueryRegistered() +2178782
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.RegisterUnobtrusiveScript() +10
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +9710113
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +83
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +974
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/735928/in-asp-net-web-application-visual-basic-the-requiredfieldvalidator-doest-work.

It looks like you have to either remove this line:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="WebForms" />
</appSettings>
```

Or change it to this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>
</appSettings>
```

Which will disable it for you.

Alternatively you could add something like this to your Global.asax

```
ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery", new ScriptResourceDefinition {
     Path = "~/scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js",
     DebugPath = "~/scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js",
     CdnPath = "http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.1.min.js",
     CdnDebugPath = "http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.1.js"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When targeting .NET 4.5 Unobtrusive Validation is enabled by default. You need to have jQuery in your project and have something like this in **Global.asax** to register jQuery properly:

```
ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery", 
new ScriptResourceDefinition {
    Path = "~/scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js",
    DebugPath = "~/scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js",
    CdnPath = "http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.1.min.js",
    CdnDebugPath = "http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.1.js"
});
```

You can also disable this new feature in **web.config** by removing the following line:

```
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="WebForms" />
```